# RAILS/DOCKER - Schema keeps reappearing after deleting the migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-7

my issue appears to pertain to mainly docker.

I got frustrated with a table that I had so I deleted it plus all associated migrations from my rails migrations.

I did make a zip file of repository before I did this so that I wouldn't lose all my work, I'm not sure if this can be affecting anything but I thought I would put it out there just in case because all of those files do technically exist somewhere else.

When I do `rails db:migrate:status` those migrations no longer appear on the list, but they still exist in schema.rb

What I have tried:

I deleted my branch that the original migration is in and started in a new one.

I tried just deleting it from schema.rb because it didn't exist anymore, but when I tried to create a table with the same name (because I need the table to be named that) it says the migration failed because that table already exists.

So then I restarted my docker container with `docker restart <container name*>` and tried running the migration again... same error.

Next I rebuilt my database, same error.

After that failed I deleted the docker container and rebuilt it from scratch.. same error.

I then deleted the repository from my computer, deleted the docker image, shut down and restarted my computer. Re-cloned the repository, rebuilt the container and still the same error.

It just keeps reappearing in the schema.

Sure I could create a new table with a different name, but I don't want the schema for a table that doesn't exist.

What should my next move be?

Comment: Did you remove the table from your Rails app's DB by using a migration to get rid of it? Are you destroying the entire DB and recreating it with `rake db:create`?

Comment: No, I was just trying to delete a model + controller that was created to generate a scaffold instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you had run migrations to update your `schema.rb` file, then you removed (dropped) a database table, maybe using your database software directly, and then you deleted the related migration files.

I don't think this has anything to do with Docker but everything with how Rails works with databases.

---

First, Rails will not know if you remove tables or make any other changes to your database directly using your database software and SQL (DDL), so the schema file is not updated based on it.

Second, Rails will not know about removing any migration files from the disk, and the schema file is not updated based on your changes.

You will always have to use migrations to keep your database structure up-to-date.

---

**Your options**

All of the below options only operate on your local database.

**Option 1:** Resetting and recreating your local database using Rails

Assumptions: you can delete your local database

You could try [resetting your database](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/active_record_migrations.html#resetting-the-database) with

```
bin/rails db:reset
```

that basically runs `bin/rails db:drop db:setup` that is described as:

> The bin/rails db:setup command will create the database, load the schema, and initialize it with the seed data.

This should recreate the database structure using your `schema.rb` and it should bring you back the frustrating table.

---

**Option 2:** Resetting and recreating your local database by restoring it from a backup

Assumptions: you have a backup, you can delete your local database

You could try restoring or importing the latest backup using your database software. Most likely, you would need to drop the database, first, but it depends on the tools used and their options available.

This should result in the structure you have in your `schema.rb` and it should give you back the frustrating table with any data you had in the backup snapshot.

---

**Option 3:** Recreating only the missing table in your local database by importing it from a backup

Assumptions: you have a backup, you do not want to delete your local database

You could try restoring or importing only the missing table using your database software.

This should result in the structure you have in your `schema.rb` and it should give you back the frustrating table. It will also import any data for that table you had in your backup snapshot.

Depending on your table definition(s), you may need to update something in the data, though, especially if other tables reference this one or this one has references to others. The data you imported might be wrong so you may want to set some references to NULL, for example, or fix them, whichever suits you better.

---

**Option 4:** Recreating only the missing table in your local database manually

Assumptions: you do not have a backup, you do not want to delete your local database

You could try recreating just the frustrating table manually without any data.

You could do this based on your `schema.rb` by translating it to SQL DDL yourself. A faster approach would be to ask one of your team members or colleagues, if any, who has an up-to-date version of the database structure to share you the SQL DDL for that table so that you could run it locally using your database software, for example.

This would result in the structure you have in your `schema.rb` and it should give you back the frustrating table.

---

**Next steps:** Finally, no matter which option you decided to implement to restore your database structure, you should create a new migration in which you call `drop_table` to remove (drop) the frustrating table correctly. That will remove the table definition from the `schema.rb` as well so that you can later create a new migration to recreate the table with the same name.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an existing application and the contents of my database do matter and I cannot delete the rest of it. When other members of my team build their docker containers the table does not exist in their containers so I think you may be right when you say its a rails issue. I just know that I cannot do a db:reset.

Comment: @purplebentleyeater Fair enough. Do you still have a database backup somewhere that you could restore locally, for example?

Comment: @purplebentleyeater What about the contents of that frustrating database table, do they also matter or can you drop that one and recreate it as you wish?

I have a couple of other ideas that I could share knowing more about your situation.

Comment: @purplebentleyeater "Unfortunately it's an existing application and the contents of my database do matter and I cannot delete the rest of it." Can you still delete your local database?

Comment: I added more options for what you can do depending on your situation. Also, all options only operate on your local database, so they should be safe to use.

Please let me know if I missed something and make another update.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I removed the volume from my container then rebuilt it and it didn't come back.

Comment: I hope that this will be useful for someone in the future because I couldn't find much on my exact situation.